# Change path in loop with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, for-loop, styles

I want change styles in javascript with loop. In Vanilla js this works:

```
for(let i=1; i<13; i++){
const path1 = document.querySelector(".path"+i);
 path1.style.animation = "animate 1.4s forwards";
}
```

But now I try learn React and I have problem to achieve the same effect. I use ref:

```
startpath1 = createRef();
for(let i=1; i<13; i++){
    this.startpath1.current.style.animation = "animate 1.4s forwards";
}
```

This code work but how I can change here "startpath1" with for example startpath + i

I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: in your first example `const` is block scoped and a new variable will be created on every iteration, holding the value of a different DOM element. To make this work with `ref`, you would similarly need to attach a `ref` to every JSX element. I'm not sure about the context, but attaching a conditional class that adds the respective styling would be much more straightforward.

Comment: Working with dom elements directly is not react way. You should rather pass the animation as a prop and use it in jsx render.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      }

    const demo = async() => {
      await sleep(100);
      if(ready1){
      for(let i=1; i<13; i++){

        this.startpath1.current.style.animation = "animate 1.4s forwards";
          await sleep(200);
           }
      }

    }
   demo()
```

This is all context of code, that's why i want this on loop, I want some break with each iteration. Could I do it with this way in react, how I change startpath with every iteration something like "startpath+i"? Can I do that at all?

I know there are other ways to do this, but I care about this, thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to insert startpath in arrays

```
const tab = [this.startpath0, this.startpath1]
for(let i=0; i<13; i++){
            tab[i].current.style.animation = "animate 1.4s forwards";
            await sleep(200);
        }
```